# How can it be proven that open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by open balls whose centers are in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let us assume that $I$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \cap I = \{r_j\}_{j = 1}^{\infty}, \delta_j = dist(r_j, \partial I)$.

How can it be proven that $I = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j)$?

If the above lemma is true, when we assume $(X, \mathcal{B})$ as measurable space, $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \{x\in X|f(x) > c\} \in \mathcal{B}$, we can prove that $\{x \in X| f(x) \in I\} \in \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Rationals are a countable dense subset of the reals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $I \neq \Bbb{R}, \emptyset$, so that $\partial I \neq \emptyset$.

Open subset of $\Bbb{R}$ are made up of non-empty bounded open intervals. Start by showing that the result holds when $I$ is a non-empty bounded open interval, then use this case to prove the general case.

Suppose $I = (a, b)$. The way to interpret $\delta_j = \operatorname{dist}(r_j, \partial I)$ is the shortest distance from $r_j$ to the boundary, and hence $(r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j)$ is the largest open interval centred at $r_j$ that is contained in $I$.

You won't need too many open intervals to cover $I$ in this case. If $\frac{a + b}{2} \in \Bbb{Q}$, then $\frac{a + b}{2} = r_j$ for some $j$ and
$$\delta_j = \min\left\{\left|\frac{a + b}{2} - a\right|, \left|\frac{a + b}{2} - b\right|\right\} = \frac{b - a}{2}.$$
That is, $I = (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j)$. If $\frac{a + b}{2} \notin \Bbb Q$, then we'll only need a couple of intervals. Choose $r_i \in \left(\frac{3a + b}{4}, \frac{a + b}{2}\right) \cap \Bbb{Q}$ and $r_j \in \left(\frac{a + b}{2}, \frac{a + 3b}{4}\right) \cap \Bbb{Q}$. Note that
$$\delta_i = r_i - a > \frac{b - a}{4},$$
hence $(r_i - \delta_i, r_i + \delta_i) = (a, 2r_i - a)$, where
$$2r_i - a > \frac{3a + b}{2} - a = \frac{a + b}{2}.$$
Similarly, $\delta_j > \frac{b - a}{4}$ and $\frac{a + b}{2} \in (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j)$, whose right endpoint is $b$. Thus,
$$I = (r_i - \delta_i, r_i + \delta_i) \cup (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j).$$
That is, when $I$ is a single bounded interval, at most two of the unioned intervals are necessary to recover all of $I$.

Now, let's suppose that $I$ is an open set. By definition, this means that, given any point $x \in I$, there exists some $\varepsilon_x$ such that $I_x := (x - \varepsilon_x, x + \varepsilon_x) \subseteq I$. This means that
$$I = \bigcup_{x \in I} I_x.$$
Since $I_x$ is a subinterval of $I$, this implies that, for any rational point $r_j \in I_x$,
$$\delta_j = \operatorname{dist}(r_j, \partial I) \ge \operatorname{dist}(r_j, \partial I_x).$$
Let $\delta_{x, j} = \operatorname{dist}(r_j, \partial I_x) \le \delta _j$. Using our result when $I$ is an interval, this implies that
$$I = \bigcup_{x \in I} I_x = \bigcup_{x \in I} \bigcup_{r_j \in I_x} (r_j - \delta_{x, j}, r_j + \delta_{x, j}) \subseteq \bigcup_{\substack x \in I \\ r_j \in I_x} (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j) \subseteq I.$$
Note that each $r_j$ occurs in some $I_x$ (e.g. $I_{r_j}$), so we have
$$I = \bigcup_{\substack x \in I \\ r_j \in I_x} (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j) = \bigcup_{r_j \in I \cap \Bbb{Q}} (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j) = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (r_j - \delta_j, r_j + \delta_j).$$